# Why does projectile-compile-project call "go build ./..."?

Tags: projectile, golang

I just started to use projectile. I use it with a go project. When I call `projectile-compile-project`, `go build ./...` runs, but after that there is no binary. The same happens when I call `go build ./...` from the shell.

- Why is `go build ./...` called and not `go build`?
- What does `./...` mean anyway? I've never seen that in ~20 years of Linux command-line usage
- What's the preferred way to customize that globally (i.e. not in `.dir-locals.el`) for `go-mode`?

Answer (score 0):

`go build ./...` will build the current directory and all subdirectories underneath it. `...` is a wildcard indicator for the go tool documented here https://golang.org/cmd/go/:

> An import path is a pattern if it includes one or more "..."
>   wildcards, each of which can match any string, including the empty
>   string and strings containing slashes. Such a pattern expands to all
>   package directories found in the GOPATH trees with names matching the
>   patterns.
>
> To make common patterns more convenient, there are two special cases.
>   First, `/...` at the end of the pattern can match an empty string, so
>   that `net/...` matches both net and packages in its subdirectories, like
>   net/http. Second, any slash-separated pattern element containing a
>   wildcard never participates in a match of the "vendor" element in the
>   path of a vendored package, so that `./...` does not match packages in
>   subdirectories of `./vendor` or `./mycode/vendor`, but `./vendor/...` and
>   `./mycode/vendor/...` do. Note, however, that a directory named vendor
>   that itself contains code is not a vendored package: cmd/vendor would
>   be a command named vendor, and the pattern cmd/... matches it. See
>   golang.org/s/go15vendor for more about vendoring.